# Botium-cli connected with smapi , Unable to connect to the skill , error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: bots, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

```
Installed botium-cli
Installed botium-connector-alexa-smapi
```

Updated configuration file according to my skill
Was able to run emulator, was able to connect to my skill I have also recorded one conversation

Now I'm getting error

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error:
>
> Skill simulation for simulation id
>   6720c6ce-e0c2-40ca-850e-fd0caaed1e3e failed with message: This
>   utterance did not resolve to any intent in your skill. Please invoke
>   your skill and try again with a different utterance or update your
>   interaction model to include this utterance before testing again"

What should I do to resolve this, I tied several utterances, tried invoking the skill on amazon developer console window. Nothing worked

[image]

Comment: so it already worked and then it stopped working?

Comment: Yes , and now It worked when I changed the value to  "ALEXA_SMAPI_API": "invocation", Previously it worked with "ALEXA_SMAPI_API": "simulation", Now it si working with "invocation "

Comment: Not changed the convo file, it is same as it was before and how this "ALEXA_SMAPI_API": "invocation" value used for triggering emulator or connecting?

Comment: Now again it was not working with "invocation", getting the response as "I can't process this at the moment" ... Again changed to "simulation" worked

Comment: simulation api and invocation api are not working the same way. pls run in verbose mode and attch logfiles here.

Comment: one hint: dont start the phrases with "alexa tell myskill ...", as the skill invocation is not part of these apis